# how to set custom value in log4net.config

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I have a custom appender in another dll
and I want to set a value "Element.MachineName" inside the log4net.config file.

It works with a static value like : `<appName ="SomeName" />` but how can I set this value with Element.MachineName ?

```
<appender name="SomeAppender" type="ConsoleApplication1.SomeAppender">
    <appName value="someName"/>
    <host value="how to set the host to this variable?" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.LayoutPattern">
          <conversionPattern value="[%date{MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}] %property{HostName} [%-5level] [%class]-[%method] - [%message] %newline" />
        </layout>
  </appender>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the global context for this purpose. See [this log4net page](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/contexts.html), it explains how you can set the properties. In your settings you could use something like this:

```html
<appender name="SomeAppender" type="ConsoleApplication1.SomeAppender">
  <file value="Log\Sessions\%property{LogFileName}.log" />
  <maxFiles value="1000" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%date %-5level - %message%newline" />
</appender>
```